# Generative AI detector for pictures (tells whether a picture was taken by a camera in the real world or not)

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence, deep-fake

I want to quickly tell whether a picture was taken using a physical camera in the physical world, or has been generated by an AI (such as DALL-E, Imagen, Midjourney, NightCafe, etc).

Ideally something that can be used online without installing anything, just with a UI to drop the image file I want to check.

Bonus if the detector:

- is free to use.
- does not need registration.
- supports several generators.

Of course for some pictures (such as a totally dark picture) it will be impossible to tell, but hopefully a tool can give a good guess, for instance by detecting patterns or by having knowledge about the image databases on which the model are based.

Comment: Is the question for camera/photorealistic images or also including illustrations? Although far from perfect, one of the methods is usually trying to find the source of the image using reverse image search engines. Unfortunately, in some areas like face portrait, AI has been so advanced that it's almost impossible to tell (ref: https://this-person-does-not-exist.com/en)

Comment: @AndrewT.: I am only interested in camera/photorealistic images. You are right that many look real to the naked eye, but hopefully some detection may still work. Even something that simply looks at the EXIF metadata or compares with the default output size of the popular AI generators would be better than nothing.